# python complex object creation

Tags: python, arrays, object

I am very new to python and need help to resolve below issue please,

I have to create python object named Error and then print it in json format:
Below is the link to image of object structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUrMy.png)

Data class

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self,fileName:str, rowId:int, rowData:str):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.rowId= rowId
        self.rowData = rowData

    def get_fileName(self):
        return self.fileName

    def set_fileName(self, fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName

    def get_rowId(self):
        return self.rowId

    def set_rowId(self, rowId):
        self.rowId = rowId

    def get_rowData(self):
        return self.rowData

    def set_rowData(self, rowData):
        self.rowData = rowData
```

Errors class:

```
from Process import Process 
from RootCause import RootCause
import json

class Errors(object):

    def __init__(self, process,rootCause):
        self.process= process
        self.rootCause= rootCause

    def get_process(self):
        return self.process

    def set_process(self, process):
        self.process = process

    def get_rootCause(self):
        return self.rootCause

    def set_rootCause(self, rootCause):
        self.rootCause = rootCause

    def __str__(self):
        return (json.dumps(self.process.get_flow))
```

Process class--

```
class Process:

    def __init__(self, id:str,flow:str,flowSubType:str):
        self.id= id
        self.flow= flow
        self.flowSubType= flowSubType

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def set_id(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def get_flow(self):
        return self.flow

    def set_flow(self, flow):
        self.flow = flow

    def get_flowSubType(self):
        return self.flowSubType

    def set_flowSubType(self, flowSubType):
        self.flowSubType = flowSubType
```

RootCause class--

```
class RootCause:

    def __init__(self,system:str, code:str,message:str,timeStamp:str):
        self.system= system
        self.code= code
        self.message= message
        self.timeStamp= timeStamp

    def get_system(self):
        return self.system

    def set_system(self, system):
        self.system = system

    def get_code(self):
        return self.code

    def set_code(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def get_message(self):
        return self.message

    def set_message(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def get_timeStamp(self):
        return self.timeStamp

    def set_timeStamp(self, timeStamp):
        self.timeStamp = timeStamp
```

Error class:

```
from Data import Data
from Errors import Errors
from Process import Process
from RootCause import RootCause
from typing import List
import json

class Error(object):
    def __init__(self,data,errors : List[Errors]):
         self.data= data
         self.errors= errors

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data=data

    def get_errors(self):
        return self.errors

    def set_errors(self, errors):
        self.errors = errors

def test():
    data = Data('a',2,'b')
    process = Process('id','flow','subtype')
    rootCause = RootCause('sys','co','message','timestamp')
    errors = [process, rootCause]
    error = Error(data,errors)
    json_data = json.dumps(error, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
    print(json_data)

test()
```

After executing Error class I m getting output as below:

```
{
"data": 
    {
       "fileName": "a",
       "rowId": 2,
       "rowData": "b"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
         "id": "id",
         "flow": "flow", 
         "flowSubType": "subtype"
        }, 
        {
         "system": "sys",
         "code": "co",
         "message": "message",
         "timeStamp": "timesta"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want help in printing the output as below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "fileName": "a",
        "rowId": 2,
        "rowData": "b"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "Process": {
                "id": "id",
                "flow": "flow",
                "flowSubType": "subtype"
            },
            "error": {
                "system": "sys",
                "code": "co",
                "message": "message",
                "timeStamp": "timestamp"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Could someone please help me in this issue.

Comment: I'm going to first ask about all these getters and setters. Did you come to Python from Java? These are not needed. We can work with attributes directly in Python.

Comment: Second, please help me find where student is defined? I can't see what student is in this line: json_data = json.dumps(student, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

Comment: What Neil says, plus this "one file per class" thingie is totally unpythonic.

Comment: @neil- question number 1 - yes i m a java developer , and i this is first time i am interacting with python.  Question number 2- sorry for mentioning student , it should be error over there. I have edited it now.u can check it now.

Comment: @bruno - ohh.i see .i m not familiar with that concept actually. I was trying to implement it in the same way as in java..would u mind letting me know about what can be the best approach to this please??

Comment: @Barkha, maybe editing this simple line of code in your `Error.py` could solve it?

`errors = [ {'Process': process}, { 'error': rootCause}]`

Please let me know!

Comment: @Barkha Neil's answer already provides quite a few useful hints, and [this (old but still relevant) article](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) too. Now the fact is that learning a new language is not only about syntax and grammar and stdlib, but also - and I'd say mostly - about learning the language's idioms and "way of thinking", which you can only do with time, practice, and reading good quality (what we label as "pythonic") code.

Comment: @Barkha a few points you may want to pay attention to: 1/ everything in Python is an object, including functions, classes and modules, 2/ Python is highly dynamic (almost everything happens at runtime - ie `class` and `def` are executable statements, not compile-time things), 3/ plain functions are ok when you don't need a full class (ie the strategy pattern is most often implemented with a plain function as "strategy" object), 4/ Python has a [simple yet powerful support for computed attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) ...

Comment: (continued) 5/ Python has a strong support for lazy evaluation (iterator protocol, generator functions and generator expressions), 6/ Python has closures and higher-order-functions (cf decorators for the most common use case), and finally 7/ Python's object model is almost fully exposed so you can hook into it in various ways (the "data model" parts of the doc is a good starting point here).

Comment: Oh and yes; Python's philosophy is that "we're all consenting adults", so don't waste your time trying to be overly defensive, typecheck arguments etc (not that there's no need for typechecking at all but that's mostly specific corner cases) - just clearly document your functions / methods expectations and that's about it.

Comment: @AshishChaubey, yes ashish, solution provided by you has worked,its giving the result in expected way.thank u

Comment: @bruno, these points metioned by you are really helpful to get some insight about pythonic ways, the links provided by you explains difference between java and python which i was really looking for. From now on ,i will surely avoid using getters and setters :-)

Comment: @Barkha actually the point is not to "avoid" getters and setters, but to not use them unnecessarily, and when you need some to use computed attributes (`property` or custom descriptor) instead of explicit ones ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways you could get the desired output

Method 1: Store the errors in a dictionary rather than a list:

```
class Error(object):
    def __init__(self,data,errors : List[Errors]):
         self.data= data
         self.errors= {"Process": errors[0], "errors": errors[1]}
```

Method 2 (recommended), write a proper asdict() function (using the Python data model is good practice where it makes sense, but the `__dict__` dunder is a bit finicky and should only really be used to inspect objects, not to get a business-case formatted object representation.

```
class Error(object):
    def __init__(self,data,errors : List[Errors]):
         self.data= data
         self.errors= errors

    def asdict(self):
        return {
            "data": self.data.__dict__, # or you can write an asdict() on every class
            "errors": {"process": self.errors[0].__dict__, "error": self.errors[1].__dict__}
        }
```

You'd call this with:

```
d = obj.asdict()
json.dumps(d)  # will probably still need the default to handle those nested objects. unless you write asdict() methods on those too and call them above.
```

Regarding the one or two other points from my comments:

- In Python we are allowed to access object attributes directly like obj.attr.
- Getters and setters aren't needed.
- If you don't want someone accessing a variable, prepend an underscore. eg self._data This doesn't actually do anything, but by convention Python coders know to leave underscore instance variables alone, or accept the consequences if they don't. So it is like a soft policy "private" variable.
- If down the line you want a getter that actually does something (eg, converts from metric to imperial before returning), it is very easy to add this in with property decorators.

Comment: this solution has worked. thank u so much for the detailed info , it helped me in getting some useful tips on python.